# Can I qualify for the foreign earned income exclusion if I am employed by a US based company?

Tags: taxes, income-tax, foreign-income

I am a US citizen considering living abroad for a full year, staying in 12 different countries for a month each ([Remote year](https://remoteyear.com/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_term=remote%20year&utm_campaign=branded&gclid=Cj0KCQjwidPcBRCGARIsALM--eNP2TICCEsuES6baG2bXEO0hZXd-WlGaBayyQmK8GBXz8igj9VkVNoaAqlUEALw_wcB)). I am planning to remain employed by the US based company I currently work for. Will the wages I earn from my US based company qualify for the Foreign Earned Income Exclusion (FEIE)?

The [IRS website](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion) does not make it clear whether or not income from a US source will qualify for the FEIE or if the income must be earned from a foreign source (relative to the US).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is *no* problem that your employer is a USA company.

There is a significant potential problem in the need to establish [bona fide residence](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-bona-fide-residence-test) in a foreign country for a full tax year. Your serial fixed-term assignments do not look like they will qualify.

**Disclaimer: I have used the exemption, but I am not a lawyer or tax professional.**

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am not planning to qualify through bona fide residence but rather, through the physical presence test. Will there be any issues with this? https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/foreign-earned-income-exclusion-physical-presence-test

Comment: That should work. Note that this significantly restricts going back to the USA for meetings, etc. [Repeat disclaimer]